# Ambiguity error with higher order lists and type families

Tags: haskell, gadt, type-families

I have a higher order list GADT defined like so:

```
data HList as where
    HNil :: HList '[]
    HCons :: a -> HList as -> HList (a ': as)
```

I can write a function that gets me the first item from that list, provided it is non-empty:

```
first :: HList (a ': as) -> HList '[a]
first (HCons a _) = HCons a HNil
```

However, if I make a new type `Cat` and a type family that merely applies every type in a type-level list to `Cat` (kind of like a type level map):

```
newtype Cat a = Cat a

type family MapCat (as :: [*]) :: [*] where
    MapCat '[] = '[]
    MapCat (a ': as) = Cat a ': MapCat as
```

And a type `CatList` which converts a list of types to a `HList` full of those types applied to `Cat`:

```
type CatList cs = HList (MapCat cs)
```

I can't write a similar function that works on `CatList`.

```
first' :: CatList (a ': as) -> CatList '[a]
first' (HCons a _) = HCons a HNil
```

It errors out with:

```
Couldn't match type ‘MapCat as0’ with ‘MapCat as’
NB: ‘MapCat’ is a type function, and may not be injective
The type variable ‘as0’ is ambiguous
Expected type: CatList (a : as) -> CatList '[a]
  Actual type: CatList (a : as0) -> CatList '[a]
In the ambiguity check for:
  forall a (as :: [*]). CatList (a : as) -> CatList '[a]
To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
In the type signature:
  Testing.fst :: CatList (a : as) -> CatList '[a]
```

What's going wrong? [Here is a gist with the entire code](https://gist.github.com/CRogers/2b595e4401f9bfc707a4).

Comment: The error message says it all.  Type families don't need to be injective - and GHC doesn't yet know enough to examine a closed type family to determine if it's injective or not. I think there's some work being done in that direction, but it won't be 7.10.

Comment: If I remember my maths correctly, an injective function is a one-to-one mapping? Also, I think the error's English is ambiguous - is it saying that 'type families must not be injective' or 'this type family is not injective (and type families must be injective)'?

Comment: Looking at it closely, this function is not injective (in some sense), as all lists of the form `'[a, b, c...]` map on `'[a]`. Is this the problem/is there any way around this? I can get it to work when I make the type signature take an input type-level list of a specific length, such as: `CatList '[a, b] -> CatList '[a]`, though.

Comment: Ah, I see the ambiguity.  It's not forbidden for type functions to be injective, it's just not required. The wording is a bit unfortunate. Injectivity means that each element is mapped to something distinct, but it doesn't need to map onto the entire space. GHC uses injectivity to determine derive `(HList a ~ HList b)` => `(a ~ b)` (since `HList` is an injective type constructor). It's not so sure in the `CatList` case, because it doesn't know `MapCat` is injective, which is what needs to be true for it to work.

Comment: @CallumRogers A one-to-one mapping is a bijection (that would mean the function is injective *and* surjective). There's some examples on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with a simpler example:

```
type family F a

err :: F a -> ()
err _ = ()
```

throws

```
Couldn't match type ‘F a0’ with ‘F a’ NB:
F is a type function, and may not be injective
The type variable a0 is ambiguous
Expected type: F a -> ()
  Actual type: F a0 -> () …
```

While this compiles fine:

```
ok :: (a ~ Int) => F a -> ()
ok _ = ()
```

And this:

```
type family F a where
    F a = a

ok :: F a -> ()
ok _ = ()
```

Here is another example, that closer to your problem:

```
data D = C

data Id (d :: D) where
    Id :: Id d

type family TF_Id (d :: D) :: D where
    TF_Id C = C

err :: Id (TF_Id d) -> ()
err _ = ()
```

The error is

```
Couldn't match type ‘TF_Id d0’ with ‘TF_Id d’ NB:
TF_Id is a type function, and may not be injective
The type variable d0 is ambiguous
Expected type: Id (TF_Id d) -> ()
  Actual type: Id (TF_Id d0) -> () …
```

But this works:

```
ok :: Id (TF_Id C) -> ()
ok _ = ()
```

and this:

```
type family TF_Id (d :: D) :: D where
    TF_Id x = x

ok :: Id (TF_Id d) -> ()
ok _ = ()
```

since `TF_Id a` immediately reduces to `a` in both cases.

So the compiler throws an error every time it cannot reduce `SomeTypeFamily a`, where `a` is some type variable, that was not determined previously.

So if we want to fix this:

```
type family TF_Id (d :: D) :: D where
    TF_Id C = C

err :: Id (TF_Id d) -> ()
err _ = ()
```

without redefining the type family, we need to determine `d` in the `err` type signature. The simplest way is

```
type family TF_Id (d :: D) :: D where
    TF_Id C = C

ok :: Id d -> Id (TF_Id d) -> ()
ok _ _ = ()
```

Or we can define a datatype for this:

```
data Proxy (d :: D) = Proxy

ok :: Proxy d -> Id (TF_Id d) -> ()
ok _ _ = ()
```

And now back to the `first'` function:

```
data Proxy (a :: [*]) = Proxy

first' :: Proxy (a ': as) -> CatList (a ': as) -> CatList '[a]
first' _ (HCons a _) = HCons a HNil
```

This compiles fine. You can use it like this:

```
main = print $ first' (Proxy :: Proxy '[Int, Bool]) (HCons (Cat 3) $ HCons (Cat True) HNil)
```

which prints `Cat3:[]`.

But the only thing the compiler must know to reduce `MapCat as` is a weak head normal form of `as`, so we do not actually need to provide this additional type information in `Proxy :: Proxy '[Int, Bool]`. Here is a better way:

```
data ListWHNF (as :: [*]) where
    LZ :: ListWHNF '[]
    LS :: ListWHNF as -> ListWHNF (a ': as)

first' :: ListWHNF (a ': as) -> CatList (a ': as) -> CatList '[a]
first' _ (HCons a _) = HCons a HNil

main = print $ first' (LS $ LS LZ) (HCons (Cat 3) $ HCons (Cat True) HNil)
```

So `first'` now receives something, that looks like the length of a list. But can we do this statically? Not so fast:

```
data ListWHNF (as :: [*]) where
    LZ :: ListWHNF '[]
    LS :: ListWHNF as -> ListWHNF (a ': as)

data HList as ln where
    HNil  :: HList '[] LZ
    HCons :: a -> HList as ln -> HList (a ': as) (LS ln)
```

throws `Data constructor LZ comes from an un-promotable type ListWHNF …`. We cannot use indexed datatypes as indices in Haskell.

Having some sort of functional dependencies, that would allow to associate a term of one type and the weak head normal form of a term of another, we could probably do the trick, but I am not aware about anything like that in GHC (but I am not an expert). In Agda this is simply

```
_^_ : ∀ {α} -> Set α -> ℕ -> Set α
A ^ 0     = Lift ⊤
A ^ suc n = A × A ^ n
```

So if the only thing, we need to infer a list, is its length, then we can replace a list with `n` nested tuples. Abusing the notation, `[?, ?] :: [*]` becomes `(? :: *, (? :: *, Lift ⊤))` and all these `?` can now be inferred automatically among with the inhabitant of `⊤` (Agda's equivalent of `()`). But in Agda there is no distinction between value-level and type-level programming, so there are no such problems at all.